# Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, streaming

I am trying my hands on kafka spark structured streaming but getting some exception like **Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`device`' given input columns: [value, offset, partition, key, timestamp, timestampType, topic];**

Attaching my code

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.ProcessingTime
case class DeviceData(device: String, deviceType: String, signal: String)

object dataset_kafka {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession
          .builder()
          .appName("kafka-consumer")
          .master("local[*]")
          .getOrCreate()
        import spark.implicits._

       spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")


    val df = spark
        .readStream
        .format("kafka")
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "172.21.0.187:9093")
        .option("subscribe", "test")
        .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
        .load()
        println(df.isStreaming)
        println(df.printSchema())

    val ds: Dataset[DeviceData] = df.as[DeviceData]

    val values = df.select("device").where("signal == Strong")

    values.writeStream
          .outputMode("append")
          .format("console")
          .start()
            .awaitTermination()


  }
}
```

Any help how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Kafka stream always produces following fields: `value`, `offset`, `partition`, `key`, `timestamp`, `timestampType`, `topic`. In your case, you're interested in `value`, but be aware that [values are always deserialized as byte arrays](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#kafka-specific-configurations), thus, type cast to string is required before deserializing JSON.

Try the following code:

```scala
import spark.implicits._

val kafkaStream =
  spark.readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "172.21.0.187:9093")
    .option("subscribe", "test")
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
    .load()

// If you don't want to build the schema manually
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
val schema = Encoders.product[DeviceData].schema

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.from_json
val ds = kafkaStream.select(from_json($"value" cast "string", schema)).as[DeviceData]

val values = ds.filter(_.signal == "Strong").map(_.device)
```